# FreeBSD iostat ms/* columns meanings

Tags: freebsd, freenas

What is the meaning of the ms/* columns on iostat (FreeBSD 11.1/FreeNAS)? I'm not seeing any details on the man pages or I'm misreading what they are

`iostat -x`

```
                        extended device statistics
device       r/s     w/s     kr/s     kw/s  ms/r  ms/w  ms/o  ms/t qlen  %b
da0            0       0      0.0      0.0     0     0     0     0    0   0
da1            0     283      0.0   9534.6     0     3    52     6    0 110
da2            0     264      0.0   7718.5     0     4    53     7    2 110
da3            0       0      0.0      0.0     0     0     0     0    0   0
da4            0       0      0.0      0.0     0     0     0     0    0   0
da5            0       0      0.0      0.0     0     0     0     0    0   0
da6            0       0      0.0      0.0     0     0     0     0    0   0
da7            0       0      0.0      0.0     0     0     0     0    0   0
da8            0       0      0.0      0.0     0     0     0     0    0   0
da9            0       0      0.0      0.0     0     0     0     0    0   0
da10           0       0      0.0      0.0     0     0     0     0    0   0
da11           0       0      0.0      0.0     0     0     0     0    0   0
cbb0           0       0      0.0      0.0     0     0     0     0    0   0
```

Comment: Good question. You may want to open a bug report on https://bugs.freebsd.org/ for this

Comment: https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=231313

Comment: Great job, @nijave!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manpages were recently updated in newer versions:

```
       The extended iostat device display, with the -x flag specified,
       shows the following statistics:

       r/s     read operations per second
       w/s     write operations per second
       kr/s    kilobytes read per second
       kw/s    kilobytes write per second
       qlen    transactions queue length
       ms/r    average duration of read transactions, in milliseconds
       ms/w    average duration of write transactions, in milliseconds
       ms/o    average duration of all other transactions, in milliseconds
       ms/t    average duration of all transactions, in milliseconds
       %b      % of time the device had one or more outstanding
               transactions
```